# How to map KIE Workbench form fields to input/ouputs and globals?

Tags: jbpm, kie-workbench

I've defined several user tasks in a few processes and would like to understand how to map the form fields both to process input/output as well as models and globals that are defined in the overarching process.

If someone could point me to some documentation that explains this, or explain how we make form fields work for us within the greater workflow, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the Forms chapter in the official docs: http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/chap-formmodeler.html